# How do I type the prime and double prime characters on OS X?

Tags: internationalization

When typing in feet and inches, the prime `′` and double prime `″` symbols are used, e.g. `5′ 5″`. How do I type these characters?

Comment: the ` is officially known as a [grave accent](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grave_accent)

Comment: Really? I thought ' and " were feet and inches.

Comment: (With ‘’ and “” for quotes.)

Comment: @davisgeek  I think your comment must have been intended for some other question?

Comment: @timothymh ' and " are "straight" or ascii quotes, the others you mention are "curly".  Wikipedia entries for feet and inches explain that prime/double prime is the most correct symbol for these.

Comment: @TomGewecke OK! You learn something new every day I guess. :)

Answer (score 12):

Using the Character Viewer, search for "Prime". You can then click "Add to Favorites" for more convenient access.

[image]

In Mavericks, the following shortcut is helpful to bring up the character viewer:

> Control + Command + Spacebar

Click the button in the top right corner to switch between the "Characters" window and "Character Viewer". Note: to get that button or the search bar to appear, you'll need to scroll up.

[image]

Comment: Actually, you don’t *need* to scroll up. Typing in the character viewer bring up the search field automatically.

Comment: The character viewer is definitely the way to go!  On my machine it's Command + Option + T though.

Comment: This is the correct answer.

Answer (score 5):

I don't know if it's the easiest way, but here's one way:

In the "International" system preferences, turn on the keyboard layout called "Unicode Hex Input".  When you need to type a prime, type <kbd>command</kbd><kbd>space</kbd> to switch to this keyboard layout, and then hold down <kbd>option</kbd> and type <kbd>2</kbd> <kbd>0</kbd> <kbd>3</kbd> <kbd>2</kbd>.  For double prime, it's <kbd>2</kbd> <kbd>0</kbd> <kbd>3</kbd> <kbd>3</kbd>.

Comment: The character viewer could help with this as well.

Answer (score 2):

**Character Palette**

---

´ (prime): `2032`

˝ (double-prime): `2033`

(thanks to [Paul Berkowitz](http://www.realgeek.com/forums/newreply.php?do=newreply&p=1618534))

**Unicode Hex Input Keyboard**

---

´ (prime): <kbd>option</kbd> <kbd>2</kbd> <kbd>0</kbd> <kbd>3</kbd> <kbd>2</kbd>

˝ (double-prime): <kbd>option</kbd> <kbd>2</kbd> <kbd>0</kbd> <kbd>3</kbd> <kbd>3</kbd>

(thanks to @Ken's [answer](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/55192/1536))

Comment: The keyboard shortcuts are wrong.  These give you the acute accent and the double acute accent (00B4,02DD) and not prime and double prime.

Comment: @TomGewecke care to provide the correct answer?

Comment: It's already here in the answer provided by Ken and the comment there.  There isn't any keyboard shortcut, you have to use the Unicode Hex layout or Character Viewer.

Comment: @TomGewecke ah, I see. It was unclear which part was incorrect. Also, it's nice to have a single consolidated correct answer.

Comment: Yes, good idea.

Answer (score 1):

### Modify the Press & Hold keys

For entering special characters such as the primes, I prefer the Press & Hold method since it's easy to remember and really quick if you [shorten the Press & Hold time](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/103563/37797).

1. Navigate to `System/Library/Input Methods/PressAndHold.app/Contents/Resources/`.
2. Backup the `Keyboard-en.plist` file.
3. Append the following to the `Keyboard-en.plist` file (before the closing `</dict></plist>`).

   ```
   <key>Roman-Accent-t</key>
   <dict>
       <key>Direction</key>
       <string>right</string>
       <key>Keycaps</key>
       <string>t ′ ″ ‴</string>
       <key>Strings</key>
       <string>t ′ ″ ‴</string>
   </dict>
   ```

Feel free to change the `Roman-Accent-t` to any character you wish, providing it does not already have Press & Hold keys assigned.

Answer (score 0):

On my new MacBook Air 2013 running Mountain Lion…

Press <kbd>⌥ alt/option</kbd> + <kbd>E</kbd> to get single prime. `´`

Press <kbd>⇧ shift</kbd> + <kbd>⌥ alt/option</kbd> and <kbd>G</kbd> to get double prime. `˝`

Comment: These are not the prime characters but the acute accent and the double accute accent.

Answer (score -1):

- <kbd>Opt-e</kbd> PRIME ´
- <kbd>Opt-j</kbd> DOUBLE PRIME ˝

Comment: I tried it and it really works.

Comment: Sorry, no, they may look the same to you, but these are not the right characters.  option-e produces the acute accent, option-j (US Extended layout) produces double accute accent.

Answer (score -1):

Try 
Prime: ⬆⌥] 
Double prime: ⬆⌥[

Comment: These are not the Prime characters but instead give you double and single quotation marks.

Answer (score -3):

Using the character palate is definitely the way forward, but instead of typing "prime" in the search box, which presented me with accented apostrophes, I found typing "apostrophe" gave me exactly what I needed.

Comment: You can't get the prime symbol by typing apostrophe, so why are you posting this as an answer to a question about how to get the prime symbol?  What did you use your apostrophe for?