# Customize accents when holding down a key

Tags: macos, keyboard, internationalization, unicode

I just noticed that if I hold down a key in mac when typing, that I get some custom bar that let's me choose between accents.

I'm a mathematician, and I like writing unicode math symbols directly (like α). Is there a way that I can customise the toolbar that pops-up, so that I can put my own mathematical unicode symbols in this toolbar ?

Comment: http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/20505/how-to-add-characters-to-the-press-and-hold-character-picker-in-os-x-lion here is an answer to Your question

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Navigate to `/System/Library/Input Methods/PressAndHold.app/Contents/Resources/`.
2. Backup the `Keyboard-en.plist` file.
3. Append the following to the `Keyboard-en.plist` file (before the closing `</dict></plist>`), changing the keycaps to be your desired space-delimited list of characters.

   ```
   <key>Roman-Accent-t</key>
   <dict>
       <key>Direction</key>
       <string>right</string>
       <key>Keycaps</key>
       <string>× ÷ √ π ∴ ∵ ≈ ≠ ∞</string>
       <key>Strings</key>
       <string>× ÷ √ π ∴ ∵ ≈ ≠ ∞</string>
   </dict>
   ```

Feel free to change the `Roman-Accent-t` to any character you wish, providing it does not already have Press & Hold keys assigned. Also see [shortening the Press & Hold time](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/103563/37797) if you're using it regularly.

Comment: I'd add, that this file could be overwritten after OS update. So make also a copy of changed plist file.