# extend the press and hold app to other keys

Tags: macos, keyboard, internationalization, unicode

Thanks to this question: [Customize accents when holding down a key](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/144562/customize-accents-when-holding-down-a-key)

I know understand how to customise the press and hold app a bit to letters. But I'm wondering, could I do the same trick for other keys. For example if press the > (shift + .) I would like to get a pop up where I can choose to select → or ≥. Would that be possible ?

Comment: Did you ever find a solution for this? I'm also hoping to extend press and hold to characters other than letters.Specifically the ? key to get ¿. This is standard behavior on the iphone, but oddly enough it's not consistent on Mac OSX El Capitan.

Comment: I think is actually a duplicate: https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/20505/how-to-add-characters-to-the-press-and-hold-character-picker-in-os-x-lion

Answer (score 2):

Okay, I think it is not possible, therefore I've made this little html app, that mimics the OSX app:

https://openuserjs.org/libs/kasperpeulen/pressandhold

You can find a demo here:http://embed.plnkr.co/jNA28BBb2JFAccPPX61p/preview

Comment: Maybe you should write that is based on the work of Quentin Thiaucourt