# macOS: increase speed of accented characters popup when typing

Tags: macos, terminal, keyboard

Does anyone know a how to increase the speed of the accent pop up when typing on Mac?

[image: accent popup example]

I am learning a new language which involves using a lot of accents, and am finding myself wishing the popup would activate quicker.

I'm sure there's a terminal command for it somewhere, but I've been searching online and can't find anything!

*(Image stolen from another post)*

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/99805/18101

Comment: you might want to change the input source in keyboard preferences